# Can textual changes possible after app status ready for sale

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I recently uploaded app into Apple app store and its published and status changes to **Ready for sale** now I want to do some textual changes in **What's New in Version**. I googled and found this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html).

**Changes available in this status are:
Remove the app from the store.
Update the app with a new version.**

Which mean that this can't be possible but I still can change text in **What's New in Version** in itunes connect against same version. I changed text and press save button after 10mins I can't see changes.

So can someone confirm that either this possible or not or this possible and taking time (as Apple usually behave)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great Apple keep its custom. And after taking half hour its updated **What's New in Version** section with my newly added text.